# How to get list of sheets from google spread sheet in php

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am using php-google-spreadsheet-client library. I don't know how to get list of sheets available in google sheets. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

function sheets($spreadsheetID) {
    $sheets = array();    
    // Load Google API library and set up client
    // You need to know $spreadsheetID (can be seen in the URL)
    $sheetService = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);   
    $spreadSheet = $sheetService->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetID);
    $sheets = $spreadSheet->getSheets();
    foreach($sheets as $sheet) {
        $sheets[] = $sheet->properties->sheetId;
    }   
    return $sheets;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of sheets by using the [`get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) method on spreadsheets:

```
sheet_metadata = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id).execute()
sheets = sheet_metadata.get('sheets', '')
title = sheets[0].get("properties", {}).get("title", "Sheet1")
sheet_id = sheets[0].get("properties", {}).get("sheetId", 0)
```

You can also check the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) for a PHP command-line application that makes requests to the Google Sheets API.

References:

- [Get list of sheets and latest sheet in google spreadsheet api v4 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245714/get-list-of-sheets-and-latest-sheet-in-google-spreadsheet-api-v4-in-python)
- [How do I access the Google Spreadsheets API in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407579/how-do-i-access-the-google-spreadsheets-api-in-php)