# Accessing properties in Google API Client Libraries (PHP)

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using the Google API Client Libraries for PHP (Beta) to make changes to a Google Sheet. I would like to access the first worksheet in the spreadsheet and then make changes to it.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($this->client);
$spreadsheet = $service->spreadsheets->get($google_sheet_id);
$sheets = $spreadsheet->getSheets();
```

Using the code above I have an array of `Google_Service_Sheets_Sheet` objects. If I `var_dump()` the contents I can see the property I need in the protected array called modelData. I want to access the sheetId property.

```
...
["modelData":protected]=>
array(3) {
  ["properties"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["sheetId"]=>
    int(123456789)
    ["title"]=>
    string(15) "Page Popularity"
    ["index"]=>
    int(0)
    ["sheetType"]=>
    string(4) "GRID"
    ["gridProperties"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["rowCount"]=>
      int(4)
      ["columnCount"]=>
      int(4)
    }
  }
...
```

I've tried everything I can think of including the standard PHP magic get/set syntax and nothing works.

```
$id = $sheets[0]->getSheetId(); // fails
$id = $sheets[0]->sheetId; // fails
$id = $sheets[0]->get('sheetId'); // fails
```

How do I access properties on this object?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the [Reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) for Sheets API
[image]

In the image above, sheets [(object)](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Sheet) have properties(object) that contains sheetID (what you want to get). To make it short, it looks like this:

```
Sheets->properties->sheetID
```

Or:

```
Sheets:{
    properties:{
         "sheetId": number,
         "title": string,
         "index": number,
         ........
 },
............
}
```

Try checking the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38271421/5995040):

```
sheet_metadata = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id).execute()
sheets = sheet_metadata.get('sheets', '')
title = sheets[0].get("properties", {}).get("title", "Sheet1")
sheet_id = sheets[0].get("properties", {}).get("sheetId", 0)
```

Hope this helps.